# jQuery - finding last hidden element ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have something like this:

```
if ($("div[id^='special-']").is(':visible')&&($(open).is(':hidden'))) {
    $('.menu-show-box').hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 200).delay(220);
    var check=0;
}
```

There are many DIVs with `.menu-show-box` class but only one will be visible at the time.

They all also have IDs that go like `#special-menu-1`, `#special-menu-2` etc.

This all works, but I'm wondering how do I get an ID of the element I just successfully hided with:

```
 $('.menu-show-box').hide('slide', {direction: 'left'},
```

If anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it like this:

```
jQuery('.menu-show-box').each(function(){
                        if (jQuery(this).is(':visible')) {
                        lastId = this.id;
                     }
             });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to go with each.

```
$('.menu-show-box').each(function(){
    $(this).hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 200).delay(220);
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The hide you're using (ui-hide) doesn't have a callback but animate does.

```
$('.menu-show-box').animate({width:'toggle'}, 200, function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
}).delay(220);​
```